# How to simplify the iteration of class instances in python?

Tags: python, class

I have a Player class that stores a list of created instances in all. I would like to do so `"P1" in Player` instead of `"P1" in Player.all`

But the code below gives an error...

```
class Player():
    all = []
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        Player.all.append(name)

    @classmethod
    def __iter__(cls):
        return cls.all
```

```
p1 = Player('P1')
'P1' in Player.all
'P1' in Player`

Traceback (most recent call last):
  at block 2, line 3
TypeError: argument of type 'type' is not iterable
```

How to simplify the iteration of class instances?

I try make `@classmethod` with `__iter__(cls)`, but it is not work…

Comment: I think the idiom `'P1' in Player` is very confusing anyway – [Explicit Is Better Than Implicit](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/).

Comment: instantiate a single Player and treat it as a sequence of  that one player ... why? Declare `Player` and `PlayerList` (or `PlayerStore` or `Playground`) separately

Comment: Yes, there probably should be a `Player` class (a single player) but also a `Game` (or something similar) class that holds all the players. Then `if p1 in game` makes more sense.

Comment: Anyway, by the looks of it, you can't make a class (type) iterable, not even with a metaclass...

Answer (score 1):

You can make the class iterable, though I wouldn't recommend it. A class should not be responsible for maintaining a collection of its instances, only defining how those instances behave. Let whoever *instantiates* `Player` keep the list of instances it needs.

---

That said, you can define a custom metaclass that defines `__iter__`, since `__iter__` has to be defined on the *type* of the thing you want to be iterable. `Player` is an instance of `IterableClass`, so `IterableClass.__iter__` is the instance method that makes `Player` iterable.

```
class IterableClass(type):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.all = []

    def __iter__(self):
        yield from self.all


class Player(metaclass=IterableClass):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        # No *instance* attribute named all, so
        # use the *class* attribute defined by IterableClass.__init__
        self.all.append(name)

p = Player('p1')
assert list(Player) == ['p1']
assert 'p1' in Player
```

---

Instance methods defined by a metaclass and class methods defined in an instance of the metaclass appear similar on the surface, but are not the same. The former is still a regular `function` object, while the latter is an instance of `classmethod`; their `__get__` methods (defined in accordance with the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)) behave differently.

Answer (score -1):

`Player` cannot be both a class and a collection at the same time.

To get a more readable syntax for player existence check, you could hold the list of players in a separate (global) variable instead of a class member (e.g. `Players`) and you could then write the conditions as `if 'P1' in Players`.

Alternatively you could write a class method (e.g. `Player.exists()`) that checks `xxx in Player.all` and write your conditions as `if Player.exists('P1')`

Comment: It *can* be, but probably *shouldn't* be.